# How to call aws lambda function recursively in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a way to call AWS Lambda function recursively? I came across class `AmazonLambdaClient` on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Lambda/TLambdaClient.html  However I'm failing to understand as how a argument will be passed which is not part of actual lambda function or function handler argument list.
For e.g. function `public void TestFuncHandler(S3Event s3)` get triggered on a S3 event, however this function is to process large batch of files. How a batch can be passed to this function?

Comment: S3Event represents an event triggered by the S3 service, not by you. What are you trying to do? Why do you think you need to call a Lambda function recursively?

Comment: From your description, should you be thinking iteratively, not recursively, for processing a batch of files?

Comment: If I iterate over a large batch, lambda will time out in 15 min. How to deal with this situation? And if we call lambda recursively, each lambda will have it's own timeout, hence completing the long running task

Comment: Yes, you can invoke Lambda (synchronously or asynchronously) from within Lambda, but that's almost certainly not what you want so let's get to the root of the problem first. Why are you iterating over a large batch? Did you explicitly invoke Lambda with this batch or did an AWS service (which one?) trigger Lambda with this batch? If AWS triggered Lambda, you typically have control over the batch size.

Comment: The lambda get triggered by AWS Service (S3 event). This S3 bucket contains a very large number of file, which require processing. Yes, I have control over the batch.

Comment: Why are you processing the entire bucket in response to a single S3 object event? If you simply want to run a given process against a batch of objects in S3 then use [S3 Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html).

Comment: Well, I believe we are deviating from the topic. The task is to achieve calling lambda function recursively. I know it's possible, however didn't find any solution so far.

Comment: You can use the AWS C# SDK to to invoke any Lambda function, including another instance of the Lambda that you're currently running in. But why you are doing this? It's probably not optimal and you're missing the opportunity to learn better ways to do whatever it is that you're trying to do but aren't willing to divulge. This has all the hallmarks of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).